# Have a react app with routing and routes gives error on refresh.what could be the reason?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

i have routing attribure in my react.js app. when i click on the route for the first time it works fine but if i refresh in the page it gives error saying cannot read property ... of null. I'm making api call from tmdb. Why i get error on refresh? Secondly, i have another route which i cannot access to it unless it is above the first route i mention. I mean when i put TvInfo above the MovieInfo tvinfo works movie info doesn't. This way only movieinfo works. If i click the above route elements first then clicking tvinfo element i get the previous clicked movie on the screen again. What could be the problem i tried many things? thanks

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import Home from './components/Home';
import MovieInfo from './components/MovieInfo';
import TvInfo from './components/TvInfo';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
render(){
return(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/:movie_id" component={MovieInfo} />
      <Route path="/:tv_id" component={TvInfo} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>

 )
}
}


export default App;
```

Comment: Since you have a designed 2 routes the same way, both accepting an id.. React Router resolves the first match. Maybe you want to redesign your routes

Comment: Something like this:
`<Route path="/movie/:movie_id" component={MovieInfo} />` 
 `<Route path="/tv/:tv_id" component={TvInfo} />`

Answer (score 0):

You need to design your Routes a little differently, Route component cannot differentiate between two separate params.

```
class App extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route path="movie/:movie_id" component={MovieInfo} />
              <Route path="tv/:tv_id" component={TvInfo} />
            </Switch>
          </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: thank you it worked!! but the second error still continues. when i refresh the page it gives error of cannot read property ... of null. could it be about the routes or about mounting the component?

Comment: when i enter the routes everything works fine. but when i refresh it gives error from the api call where it says cannot read property "backdrop_path"(which is coming from api call) of null.

Comment: Can you show the code of component where you get this error

Answer (score 0):

this is my movieInfo component

```
class MovieInfo extends React.Component{

 render(){


 return(
  <div>
    <p style={{marginLeft:'47%',fontSize:25}}>{this.props.selectedMovie.original_title}</p>
    <img  style={{marginLeft: '20%'}}
    src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w780${this.props.selectedMovie.backdrop_path}`} alt="moviebackdrop"/>
  <div style={{float:'right',marginRight:45}}>
    <p>Release Date: {this.props.selectedMovie.release_date}</p>
    <p>Vote: {this.props.selectedMovie.vote_average}<Icon name="star" color="yellow" /></p>
  </div>
    <p style={{width:800,marginLeft: '20%'}} >{this.props.selectedMovie.overview}</p>
    <p>{this.props.data.homepage}</p>
  </div>
)}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return{
selectedMovie:state.movie.selectedMovie,
 }
}
```

to be able to display this screen i have another component where you show the images for the movies. when i click on the image it renders movieInfo component.
here is my image component.

```
 selectMovie = () => {
 this.props.setMovie(this.props.movie)
 }


render(){
return(
<Link to={"movie/" + this.props.movie.id}>
  <div onClick={() => this.selectMovie()}>
    <div className="item">
      <img className="img"
      src={`http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w342${this.props.movie.backdrop_path}`} alt="moviebackdrop"/>
      <p className="title">{this.props.movie.original_title}</p>
      <p className="overview">{this.props.movie.overview}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</Link>
)}
}
```